# How to validate DB2 authentication from Java

Tags: java, db2

Need to validate the user authentication in DB2 from Java before creating ant Database or executing any SQL query.

Is there any DB2 command for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to check authentication to connect to database OR the registered user authentication?

Comment: I want to check authentication to connect to database also authentication to create databse.

Comment: Easiest way is to try to connect with the credentials.  If you can't connect, the credentials are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to run on db2cmd to verify the user name

```
db2icrt <db2_instancename> -u <userName> , <passWord>
```

But how to use this from Java, i have no idea.

Comment: Thanks @Kishore, the command works on db2cmd but also validates if its a network user. I need to restrict those user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DB2Jcc** - *IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ* diagnostic utility to test database connectivity and validate DB2 authentication using Java. A sample command and it's output is shown as below:

```
$ java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -url jdbc:db2://myhost.bluemix.net:446/MYDB -user myuserid -password mydbpasswd

[jcc][10521][13706]Command : java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -url jdbc:db2://myhost.bluemix.net:446/MYDB -user myuserid -password ********

[jcc][10516][13709]Test Connection Successful.

DB product version = DSN11015
DB product name = DB2
DB URL = jdbc:db2://myhost.bluemix.net:446/MYDB
DB Drivername = IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
DB OS Name = Linux
$
```